# DSLR Canon Videocapture in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, video-capture

I need to capture frame from a DSLR camera. I know that i can use 
Videocapture cap(0); 
for capture from default webcam. If i connect with usb the camera and run the code, It seems like he cant find the camera.
What should i do for capture from the DSLR?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have found getting OpenCV to work with anything besides a basic webcam almost impossible. In theory, I think it uses the UVC driver, but I have had almost 0 luck getting it to read. One thing you can try is using VLC and see if you can capture a video stream from your camera with it. If you can you might get lucky and figure which camera or video device the DSLR actually is.

If your DSLR has a development SDK maybe you can capture frame using their interface and then use OpenCV for processing. I do this for a project. I have a 3rd party SDK that I use to find and control the camera and them I move the video data into OpenCV (EmguCV) for processing.

Doug